# Jenkins disables project builds on branches after a pull request is issued

Tags: git, jenkins, github

Note: I only have Jenkinsfile set up in one of my branches, not the master.

I have setup Git webhooks to monitor push events to my Github repository. However, I am noticing that my Jenkins builds are working fine (picking up push events, triggering builds) as branches, but after a pull request is issued, my branch build gets disabled in the **`Branches`** tab of my project.

[image]

However, I do see the new PR listed in my **`Pull Requests`** tab. But now, when I push to Github, the new commits are not triggering builds anymore. In my branches tab, my old branch is now crossed out. 
[image]

**How do I force Jenkins to keep building my branches? I would like to continue building from a branch, even if a PR has been issued.**

Comment: What plugin are you using?

Comment: The standard http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Github+Plugin plugin and https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin plugin.

Answer (score 10):

That's because you have an on going PR for that branch, whenever the PR reaches any final status, your disabled branch will be enabled again.

Answer (score 2):

I guess if change your configuration of Behaviours by changing discover branches' strategy to All Branches then your issue might get fixed. By default it is set as Exclude Branches that are also filed as PRs