# Jenkins leaves GitHub branches disabled once PR completes

Tags: git, jenkins

I'm experiencing similar issues to those in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55388335/jenkins-disables-project-builds-on-branches-after-a-pull-request-is-issued), but the PR has completed its pipeline and *still* the branch is marked as disabled:

[image: the branches tab for this repo in the Jenkins UI] [image: the pull requests tab for this repo in the Jenkins UI]

(PR #99 is the one associated with this branch.) This means I can't get my PR merged, as you can see on the GitHub PR status:

[image: the checks status on the GitHub PR page]

How do I get Jenkins to run the pipeline for the branch?

*Update: I think this may be happening when I force-push changes to my branch, but that's a practice I've had for a while now and I haven't seen this happen until a few days ago.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is normal behavior after all. Once a PR is opened, the corresponding `/branch` check is disabled. The real problem was my GitHub configuration: the PR should not require the `/branch` check in order to allow merging.